# Update WebBrowser content

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have the following controls on a form: Memo1, Memo2 and WebBrowser.
OnExit procedures of controls Memo1 and Memo2 are to update the WebBrowser content with the content of Memo1.Text and Memo2.Text. I use the following procedures for this:

```
procedure LoadBlankDoc(WB: TWebBrowser);
begin
  WB.Navigate('about:blank', EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  while WB.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Sleep(0);
  end;
end;

procedure CheckDocReady(WB: TWebBrowser);
begin
  if not Assigned(WB.Document) then
    LoadBlankDoc(WB);
end;

procedure LoadDocFromString(WB: TWebBrowser; const HTMLString: string);
var
  v: OleVariant;
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  CheckDocReady(WB);
  HTMLDocument := WB.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  v[0] := HTMLString;
  HTMLDocument.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
  HTMLDocument.Close;
end;
```

The problem is that when the Memo1 control is active and we click in the WebBrowser area and then click in the Memo2 area, then the cursor does not appear or disappears after the first character is entered. Sometimes the application gets lost and you can't enter text into Memo at all.
One more thing: when I move between Memo1 and Memo2, everything works as it should. The problem occurs when OnExit occurs by clicking in the WebBrowser area.
What could be the reason?

2023-05-09

My further analysis of the topic...

Posting this problem on the forum, I rather suspected some error in the LoadDocFromString procedure.
However, further experiments showed:

If we have set the focus on some Memo control, eg. Memo1, then we click on the WebBrowser area, then the focus is removed from Memo1 ... but! the Memo1Exit procedure is not executed.

If we now click on some other control, e.g. Memo2, now Memo1Exit is executed.

And everything works fine...

However, it is enough in the OnExit event of the Memo control put a call to LoadDocFromString ... and the problems begin.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but could an alternative solution be to use TEdgeBrowser and NavigateToString?  https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.NavigateToString

Comment: Thanks Matthias B. I will try. Before that, however, I need to understand how to use TEdgeBrowser, because currently NavigateToString does not load any text to EdgeBrowser :)

Comment: I notice, too, that NavigateToString seems to work only after you've first done Navigate to some web page. Odd. Maybe a bug in TEdgeBrowser? EDIT: Put EdgeBrowser.CreateWebView in FormCreate, and NavigateToString seems to work.

Comment: Without changes. EdgeBrowser is in background color Forms and no text on it. EdgeBrowser.Navigate('https://www.google.com') also doesn't work.

Comment: That sounds like the symptom you get when WebView2Loader.dll is not present in your EXE file folder.

Comment: Still not working. I suppose this already qualifies for a separate thread: "How to get EdgeBrowser to work?" :)  I have Community Edition - maybe that's the reason? What bothers me more is why, after clicking on the WebBrowser area, the OnExit event procedure is not executed.
And I suppose it will be exactly the same with EdgeBrowser.

Comment: Maybe WebView2 (Microsoft's runtime that is the foundation for TEdgeBrowser) is not installed? It is downloadable from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section

Comment: I installed WebView2 Runtime. EdgeBrowser still not working.

Comment: Then it's a total mystery. Just repeating the checklist: (1) Install WebView2 runtime from the Microsoft download page. (2) Put WebView2Loader.dll (correct version of it, note that 32-bit and 64-bit versions are both called WebView2Loader.dll, but are different files) into the folder where the Delphi EXE is, (3) Use TEdgeBrowser in a Delphi VCL application and make sure the EXE is in the same folder as the DLL from (2).

Comment: I finally got EdgeBrowser to work. Indeed, the reason for not working is the wrong version of WebView2Loader.dll. There were about a dozen WebView2Loader.dll files on my drive, but it only works with the version I found in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\...". After starting the program, a subdirectory "programname.exe.WebView2" is created, in which there are over 50 subdirectories and over 100 files. Is it standard?

Comment: Good! Maybe all the other WebView2Loader.dll files happened to be 32-bit ones, and the one under Microsoft Office was 64-bit, and that happened to be the needed one? I think there should be only exactly two versions of the DLL, one for 32-bit and one fore 64-bit. Yes, the User Data Folder is where cookies/cache etc is stored. It's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=win32  In Delphi, you can change the folder name and placement with the EdgeBrowser.UserDataFolder property.